# Google AJAX Feed API: How to display 6 blog entries rather than the default 4 one

Tags: javascript, ajax, feed, google-api

I need some help in using Google AJAX Feed API. As we know by default this API lists latest 4 blog entries. What code changes to do so that it shows say 5 or 6 latest entries? I cant figure it out in code.

Here is the example function:

google.load("feeds", "1");

```
function initialize() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml");
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
        container.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Any help will appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml");
feed.setNumEntries(6)
feed.load(function(result) {...
```

Try that.
[Read more here.](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html)